# Prove that $\mathcal{O}_{(0,0)} = \{(0, 0)\}.$ The action is given by $\lambda \cdot (x, y) = (\lambda x, \lambda y).$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I would like to show that they are subsets of each other. I have shown that $\mathcal{O}_{(0,0)} \subseteq  \{(0, 0)\}$ but I need help showing the other way please.

Comment: What values can $\lambda, x,$ and $y$ take?

Comment: Could you make explicit the part you have shown, please?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lambda\cdot (x, y)$ is an action, the orbit of each element $(a, b)$ contains $(a,b)$ by letting $\lambda=e$. Can you conclude the result from this?

Comment: Does this answer your question, @PhysicsBish?